# Pandas Create Percentages from Category Sums

Tags: pandas, multi-index, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset of website traffic, for about 2000 websites over a period of a month, tabulated by the type of device from which the traffic originated:

```
In [12]: df.sample(10)
Out[12]:
         date                  device  nb_uniq_visitors  site_id
11 2017-10-31                     Tv               0.0   3331.0
6  2017-10-22            Car browser               0.0    503.0
7  2017-10-22                 Camera               0.0   3259.0
7  2017-10-08            Car browser               0.0    630.0
3  2017-10-23                 Camera               0.0    118.0
0  2017-10-12                Desktop               1.0   4769.0
11 2017-10-31                     Tv               0.0    361.0
5  2017-10-12                Phablet               0.0   2999.0
9  2017-10-17  Portable media player               0.0   1725.0
0  2017-10-13                Desktop            2410.0   1004.0
4  2017-10-13                all                 900.0   1271.0
```

Note that the `all` category of the `device` column represents the total of all devices, therefore it could serve as the denominator of the percentage calculation.

I want to see the percentages of device types for each website, I'm imagining the output looking like this (I manually calculated the below for example):

```
                               nb_uniq_visitors
site_id device
74.0    Camera                         0.00
        Car browser                    0.00
        Console                        0.00
        Desktop                        0.56
        Feature phone                  0.00
        Phablet                        0.01
        Portable media player          0.00
        Smart display                  0.00
        Smartphone                     0.37
        Tablet                         0.05
        Tv                             0.00
        Unknown                        0.00
        all                            1.00
96.0    Camera                         0.00
        Car browser                    0.00
        Console                        0.00
        Desktop                        0.64
        Feature phone                  0.00
        Phablet                        0.01
        Portable media player          0.00
        Smart display                  0.00
        Smartphone                     0.29
        Tablet                         0.06
        Tv                             0.00
        Unknown                        0.01
        all                            1.00
```

I used `groupby` to group by `site_id` and `device`:

```
In [23]: sl = df.groupby(['site_id', 'device']).sum()

In [24]: sl.head(25)
Out[24]:
                               nb_uniq_visitors
site_id device
74.0    Camera                              0.0
        Car browser                         0.0
        Console                             1.0
        Desktop                         10534.0
        Feature phone                       0.0
        Phablet                           178.0
        Portable media player               4.0
        Smart display                       0.0
        Smartphone                       6955.0
        Tablet                           1022.0
        Tv                                  1.0
        Unknown                            62.0
        all                             18757.0
96.0    Camera                              0.0
        Car browser                         2.0
        Console                             6.0
        Desktop                        118157.0
        Feature phone                       0.0
        Phablet                          1061.0
        Portable media player              73.0
        Smart display                       0.0
        Smartphone                      53292.0
        Tablet                          11060.0
        Tv                                  2.0
        Unknown                          1717.0
        all                            185370.0
```

How do I translate the above from aggregate values to percentages? Or is there a better way entirely?

Comment: The logic would go as follows: 1. Get the total sum of `nb_uniq_visitors` 2. apply a lambda on each row of the dataframe at column `nb_uniq_visitors` dividing it by the total. E.g., `df['nb_uniq_visitors'] = df['nb_uniq_visitors'].apply(lambda row: row/sum(df['nb_uniq_visitors']))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) for select `all` rows with dividing by [`DataFrame.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html):

```
sl = df.groupby(['site_id', 'device']).sum()
a = sl.div(sl.xs('all', level=1))
print (a)
                               nb_uniq_visitors
site_id device                                 
74.0    Camera                         0.000000
        Car browser                    0.000000
        Console                        0.000053
        Desktop                        0.561604
        Feature phone                  0.000000
        Phablet                        0.009490
        Portable media player          0.000213
        Smart display                  0.000000
        Smartphone                     0.370795
        Tablet                         0.054486
        Tv                             0.000053
        Unknown                        0.003305
        all                            1.000000
96.0    Camera                         0.000000
        Car browser                    0.000011
        Console                        0.000032
        Desktop                        0.637412
        Feature phone                  0.000000
        Phablet                        0.005724
        Portable media player          0.000394
        Smart display                  0.000000
        Smartphone                     0.287490
        Tablet                         0.059664
        Tv                             0.000011
        Unknown                        0.009263
        all                            1.000000
```

Detail:

```
print (sl.xs('all', level=1))
         nb_uniq_visitors
site_id                  
74.0              18757.0
96.0             185370.0
```

Comment: I use output form `In [24]: sl.head(25)`, this is only way ;)

Comment: @Wen The `all` data was included in the input data.

Comment: @JosephDasenbrock then why you sample data did not included that ?

Comment: @Wen I just showed the `sample` of the input data and it didn't happen to include the `all` category

Comment: @JosephDasenbrock ok , we need to clarify it , df.sample(10) is the sample data we usually treat ..

Comment: @jezrael To clarify, the `level=1` arg in the `xs` method specifies the second level of the multiindex, correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You are right. `axis=0` is default value, so should be omit